# mix of asp.net and VSTO project

Tags: c#, asp.net, vsto

I have  a web site using asp.net mvc4, and a VSTO automation (client side) that need to update and get some data from my web site.

Actually I'm trying to use HttpWebRequest object to perform the dialog. between VSTO and web.

For now I'm thinking on return some jSon objects from web to VSTO. But how can I do to send from VSTO to web ?

Is better approach send XML ? if yes what is the current way to do this in c#.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a C# object that matches the object sent via JSON, and then use have it deserialize via the .net default serializer or json.NET.  Investigate the DataContract attribute for more information.

Comment: Very tks for you help, maybe do you have a sample, I'm totally lost.

Comment: Sure.  Do you have the JSON string that the VSTO returns?